# I can't find any task in Django admin

Tags: python, django-admin, celery, django-celery

I can't find any task status in Django Admin.

All 5 tables remains hopelessly empty:

- Crontabs
- Intervals
- Periodic tasks
- Tasks
- Workers

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'djcelery',
    #...
)

BROKER_TRANSPORT = "mongodb"
BROKER_URL = "mongodb://xxx:yyy@zzz"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Here is my tasks.py:

```
from celery import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Now, when I want to try it:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info &
python manage.py shell
>>> from apps.me_core import tasks
>>> tasks.add.delay(2,3)

[2013-07-07 11:06:12,274: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: apps.me_core.tasks.add[9e5bbf1b-a0df-4fa4-851e-281dc79df866]
[2013-07-07 11:06:12,310: INFO/MainProcess] Task apps.me_core.tasks.add[9e5bbf1b-a0df-4fa4-851e-281dc79df866] succeeded in 0.0213570594788s: 5
```

## EDIT

I've been able to find all the tombstones via `python manage.py shell`.

```
>>> from djcelery.models import TaskMeta
>>> TaskMeta.objects.count()
51
>>> TaskMeta.objects.db
'default'
>>> TaskMeta.objects.current_engine()
'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
>>> conn = TaskMeta.objects.connection_for_write()
>>> conn.connection
<connection object at 0x7fca897659b0; dsn: 'dbname=mydbname user=postgres password=xxxxxxxx host=localhost', closed: 0>
```

Where are they stored?? I can't find them using pgAdmin3 nor Django admin! This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Did you run syncdb yet, sorry to ask the obvious but stuff like this has happened to me before,

Comment: Yes I did a `python manage.py migrate` (I am using south). However, the table have been created and I can access them in the admin. It's just that no table ever get any row added.

Comment: Okay, so the tables were created then?

Comment: If you have something like pgAdmin for mongoDB, take a look at the schema and the tables inside, and see if the data was added. There could potentially be 2 problems, one being that the database interface is not working, and the other being that the admin interface not working.

Comment: Using pgAdmin, I see that the tables are empty : `djcelery_crontabschedule`, `djcelery_intervalschedule`, `djcelery_periodictask`, `djcelery_peridictask` , `djcelery_taskstate`, `djcelery_workerstate`

Comment: Did you make sure to hit save, because your code seems to look fine from here.

Comment: I may not have phrased the question properly. I am new to Django Celery and I've just made it through the tutorial. When I run `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info` followed by `python manage.py shell` (see OP), I am expecting to see some new rows added to the djcelery tables (which one, I don't even know). Otoh I can see my broker have some new tables added (`messages`, `messages.route`, `messages.broadcast`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33027/discussion-between-btoueg-and-games-brainiac)

Answer (score 0):

The table I was looking for is `celery_taskmeta`.

It is a `celery` table, not a `django-celery` one.